# Redundancy: If they should

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Today’s [horoscope](http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/horoscopes/daily?c=sagittarius) on New York Daily News says (the link may be broken after tomorrow):

> **If** they **should** find out something before you had a chance to tell them, it could cause real friction.

How formal is it to say **if** and **should** in the same clause when expressing the conditional mood? Or is that redundant?

In speech, I say:

> **If** they find out something before you had a chance to tell them, it could cause real friction.

In writing, I say:

> **Should** they find out something before you had a chance to tell them, it could cause real friction.

I think I should avoid using them both in one clause if that’s redundant.

Comment: The original is not incorrect, but your versions are more elegant.

Comment: In the context of the horoscope, "*should*" reads as "*happen to*"; I don't find "*If* they *happen to* find out before ..." redundant.  YMMV.

Comment: It's funny—I was just thinking that even if the opening phrase were "If they should happen to find out..." it wouldn't be redundant, strictly speaking. It would just be an idiomatic way to express an idea that you could get to by shorter routes if you preferred.

Comment: Dan, Sven, I guess this subtlety means a lot to you, and I respect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form you're asking about is not redundant. The fact is that both **should you** and **if you should** are used when the speaker implies that a given situation is very unlikely to happen. You may also use the expression **if you happen to** which carries a similar meaning to the expression you've indicated. I would also argue that the constructions **if you should/happen to** bear a subtle dose of politeness. This can be compared with the form **if you will** used with regard to polite requests. Anyway, check the examples below:

> 1. If you should visit our parents, greet them from me.
> 2. If you happen to visit our parents, greet them from me.

Link: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv48.shtml

You may also consider **should** in one clause with **if** as an indicator of putative sense.

> "Let me know if you *should* hear some more news."

Source:

Quirk, Randolph, Sidney Greenbaum, Geoffrey Leech, and Jan Svartvik.
*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language.* New York: Longman. 1985. p. 234

Comment: While this is what that web page says, it really isn't the way *should* is used in real life.

Comment: I’m fuzzy about the difference in the likelihood of happening as BBC says… And I don’t know how much of a big deal it is to be distinct about. That’s their delicacy but the tastes are different in my neighborhood. A judgment call?

Comment: You're totally right. That depends on your personal opinion. The difference is very subtle, hardly, if at all, noticeable.